Что означает эта связь в UML?
Неоднократно встречаю данные связи на диаграммах UML:

Что означают эти связи и как они называются?
Я понимаю что первая это агрегация, вторая композиция, но что означает стрелка-ассоциация?
И когда нужно применять эти связи?
